# Why i have this error when run node index.js and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code run well on browser, however when run by node index.js I get this error :

```
let x = (agr[item.id] ??= { id: item.id, count: 0 });
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

This is my code

```
var array  = [{"id":1,"count":100},{"id":2,"count":200},{"id":1,"count":200}]
const groupedData = array.reduce((agr,item)=>{
    let x = (agr[item.id] ??= { key: item.id, count:0 });
    x.count+=(item.count);
    return agr
},{});
const result = Object.entries(groupedData).reduce((agr, item) => {
    agr.push(item);
    return agr;
}, []); 
console.log(result);
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: `let x = (agr[item.id] ??= { key: item.id, count:0 });` should be `let x = (agr[item.id] = { key: item.id, count:0 });`

Comment: My code run very well on browser. The result is 1 array:                       [{"1","key:1,count:300"},{"2","key:2,count:200"}]

Comment: ```??=``` only supported in Node 15.x. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) is a very new feature to JavaScript.

Your version of Node.js is too old to support it.

Upgrade to Node.js 15.0.0 or (preferably) newer.